# Merging two arrays without replacing with empty

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to merge two arrays, without replacing elements if replacement is null/empty?

Using `array_merge` as follows, replaces an item that has data with nothing:

**$original_array:** (before merge)

```
Array ( 
    [test1] => Test 1
    [test2] => Test 2
)
```

**$new_array:** (after merge)

```
Array ( 
    [test1] => Test 1
    [test2] =>  
)
```

Is the only alternative using a `foreach` and rebuilding the array with a condition?

**Example of what I would like to happen:**

If 'test2' is empty on merge, then the $original_array['test2'] item would remain as 'Test 2' value.

If 'test2' is not empty on merge, then the $new_array['test2'] item would be used.

Comment: can you show two arrays and there result when they merge with what you want?

Comment: Perhaps you could first filter the array for empty values.

Comment: You also can use array arithmetics, so `$a = $b + $c`;

Comment: @AhmedsaysReinstateMonica I've just added a short example. Hope that helps explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `array_filter()` - this will remove any *empty* elements and then merge the results...

```
array_merge($a1, array_filter($a2))
```

The only problem is that `array_filter()` will also remove 0's and `''` elements, so you may want to process it more specifically...

```
print_r(array_merge($a1, 
    array_filter($a2, function($data) { 
                          return $data !== null ; 
                      }
    )));
```

Comment: Thank you Nigel. I hadn't thought to use 'array_filter'. This is perfect, as I would also refuse just 0.